# How would one achieve a gradient transparency in Blender eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, transparency

[image]

I want to be able to create a mesh that gradually fades in and out in the render mode of eevee similar to this thread: https://blenderartists.org/t/solid-to-transparent-gradient/539625/3 I also don't want the glassy aspect in this thread: [Eevee Transparency gradient](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144551/eevee-transparency-gradient)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the kind of material you can create to have the same result: plug a *Texture Coordinate* into a *(Converter) Separate XYZ*, use the Y output (or X or Z depending on your plane orientation) and plug it into the factor of a *Mix Shader* that mixes a *Diffuse* with a *Transparent* node. In Eevee don't forget to choose *Alpha Blend* in the *Material > Settings > Blend Mode*. You can put a *ColorRamp* between the *Separate XYZ* and the *Mix Shader* if you want more control on the gradient.

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a right step in the direction, but I'm having three problems; 1. All though I can see the transparency when I'm loaded into Eevee, I can't see the transparency when I render an image of the object. Not sure if I have to enable a render setting to render Alpha Blend. 2. I would like to be able to control just how far the transparency ends/begins. 3. Some of the meshes I apply the node tree to seem to have a weird concentration: https://i.gyazo.com/342a35492a24eab48c8c49f76e3e7af7.mp4 https://i.gyazo.com/cb4bc37d0e510a3502b28051de182033.mp4

Comment: I don't have the exact same result as you, I have a big halo around your object when I watch through the camera but that's because you've enabled its Depth of Field, disable or reduce it. Disable the Show Backface option in the Material Settings otherwise you'll see the other faces by transparency and it will make the object more opaque. For the gradient, as I said, you can control it if you put a ColorRamp between the Separate XYZ and the Mix Shader. Also there's a Shader to RGB that I don't really know.

Comment: Thank you very much, Moonbots. There's only one last issue that I'm having with the render. I'm very rudimental when it comes to node editing, so I'm having an issue with the gradient part in the render. There's an immediate cutoff as if the gradient aspect never existed, it shows up fine in Eevee however, maybe it's a visible macro issue, is there any way to prolong the solid to transparent feature perhaps using another color ramp? https://i.gyazo.com/9ac52dd57c88c97a11fbc00974227fe1.png https://i.gyazo.com/333bef476eecad15dc6ef867a2b7b26f.png

Comment: I'm not sure why you get this result in render actually, I don't have the same result, I hope someone will tell

Comment: It's a macro issue. For whatever reason, Blender render won't acknowledge the fade in rendered image, but saving it as a file will make the fade obvious. Thanks, moonboots. Just need to know how to make the transparent to solid transition last longer instead of it being short.

Comment: please prepare a file as simple as possible with just one camera and a plane with a simple material with the mix between diffuse and transparent so that we can test further, and share again. For the gradient control you can put a ColorRamp as I said but I doubt this is your problem here

Comment: Sorry, here you go: https://pasteall.org/blend/d9fb45c499194dd68ff98eb5f24411ea I'm also running into an issue where the contrast between the transparent gradient mesh clashes with other meshes via a white border whenever it's rendered as an image not when it render view in Eevee is enabled, it's very obvious. https://i.gyazo.com/663928fef421915866b390967b7ed7dd.png https://i.gyazo.com/0a81215ed0df5b701d1f20e8bcdb7ece.png How would I remove the obnoxious white outline between the two objects?

Comment: Here is what I get (if I disable the camera's Depth of Field), it looks normal to me (except I don't know how how the Shader to RGB works so I'm not sure about this part of your material): https://zupimages.net/up/21/33/vbds.jpg ... I agree that the ColorRamp is a bit surprising as its middle is not 50% black, I don't know why...

Comment: ColorRamp in B-Spline mode with a third needle seems to give a better gradient result: https://zupimages.net/up/21/33/nxil.jpg

Comment: Alright, there's still the issue with that horrid white border that separates the mesh on top of the transparent body. Using B-spline doesn't make much of a difference either whenever I render an image: https://i.gyazo.com/af0e053b927047ed0836dbda9642b337.png Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: unfortunately I can't help because I don't see the same problem when I render...   :((

Comment: Good news, as soon as you said "I don't see the same problem" I knew it was an issue with the blender Version I had. I was using 9.1, but when I updated to 9.3 I noticed the border issue was slightly resolved. Same with the image render. https://i.gyazo.com/e01f312041728c7749909a35e44cd7de.png the border has definitely been reduced, but how would I reduce it even more?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/5c3ae9af8018a8ec6ef75a9390e72716.png I know the problem seems menial, but the render still has the white border that separates the body and equipment if you look hard enough.

Comment: This part right here, you can still see the white border: https://i.gyazo.com/073315402c4e91075b5d0f280d27fe77.png

Comment: see my render, it's seems ok: https://zupimages.net/up/21/33/uxsr.jpg